# Mobile login with facebook security

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I have implemented facebook login in my app. By I need to get additional info about user from my webservices.
How to make this in secure way? Passing only user facebook id is insecure, because everyone who knows facebook id will be available to get this info.

As I understand I need to pass User Access Token. How this need to be handled on the server?

Comment: As I understand you need just to pass token to webservice and webservice will take from facebook needed info using this token?

Comment: Please read through android facebook sdk integration tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/